# Read a pdf grocery flyer with python

Tags: python, pdf

Hello I would like to read the attached file, it is a grocery flyer.
I tried with pypdf2, tika and tabula and the text result is empty.
Someone would know with which package it is possible to read this type of file

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z307u.png)

[the flyer I would like read](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qmqjOd-qI_6bMkZffTJnSiH3jPd72R1O/view?usp=sharing)

thankful

Answer (score -1):

This file contains images, rather than as text. I think OCR(Optical Character Recognition) algorithms to be implemented.